# IIRF Rewrite Rule for IIS7

Tags: iis-7, iirf

i am using IIRF v2.1 for Rewrite Rule

i write on rule like this but its not working

```
RewriteRule ^(prod|pag|staf)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ $1.php?iid=$2 [QSA,L]
```

if i use follwoing url

http://localhost/prod/22/new-item

what i need actual URL is
http://localhost/prod.php?iid=22

yes working version is

RewriteRule /^(prod|pag|staf)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /$1.php?iid=$2 [QSA,L]
but problem here is all the style and include files are not included.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have other rules that work? Trying to narrow down if it's related to your rule or the IIRF config.

Comment: For the person that voted to close, this is programming related because it's really a regex question.

Comment: I think this might be more appropriate for serverfault .

Comment: RewriteRule /^(prod|pag|staf)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /$1.php?iid=$2 [QSA,L]
but problem here is all the style and include files are not included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just write url like this

RewriteRule ^/(prod|pag|staf)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /$1.php?iid=$2 [QSA,L]

and put / before your style sheets and other includes

like

if your old style sheet is include like this

```
   style/style.css
```

chnage it to

```
  /style/style.css
```

same for image and links.
hope this will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex  doesn't allow for new-item to follow the final slash.

`RewriteRule ^(prod|pag|staf)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ $1.php?iid=$2 [QSA,L]`

The /?$ sequence that ends the pattern says... a slash (maybe) and then the end of the string.  Your URL, however, does not end in a slash.  It ends with a slash and the text "new-item".

A regex that captures *that* would be something like this:

`RewriteRule ^(prod|pag|staf)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/? $1.php?iid=$2 [QSA,L]`

...which says, you don't care what comes after the optional slash, and because you are using QSA, then any query string in the original URL is appended to the outgoing URL.

But that would basically discard the "new-item" portion of the incoming URL request, which I am not sure you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you're URLs will always contain the numbers then the slug, this regex will get each part:

```
^(prod|pag|staf)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?
```